# Como comparar memória usada por 2 processos

Tags: vb.net

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um programa em vb.net que encontra alguns processos, pega o PID dos mesmos, e depois coleta algumas informações sobre eles.

O problema é quando tem 2 processos iguais. Nesse caso, eu precisaria que ele visse qual dos dois está utilizando mais memória no momento, e deletar o outro da listbox. Meu code para achar os PID's:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.Focus()

    For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Proc.ProcessName)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(Proc.Id)
        Proc.Start()
    Next

Private Sub Proc_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Proc.Tick
'variáveis
Dim actualProcess as String
Dim ListBox1Items as String
Dim actualProcessExists as Boolean = False
Dim ProcID as Integer
'----------------------------------------------
actualProcess = "explorer"
    ListBox1Items = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

'Checando se o processo existe
    For ia As Integer = ListBox1Items To 0 Step -1
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ia
        If ListBox1.SelectedItem = actualProcess Then
            actualProcessExists = True
        Else
            Proc.Stop()
            Proc2.Start()
        End If
    Next
'----------------------------------------------------------

'Adicionando PID à outra ListBox

    If actualProcessExists = True Then
For i As Integer = ListBox1Items To 0 Step -1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ia
        If ListBox1.SelectedItem = actualProcess Then
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        ProcID = ListBox2.SelectedItem
        ListBox3.Items.Add(ProcID)
    Else
   Proc.Stop()
   Proc2.Start()
End if
End Sub
```

Bom, o que eu precisava era que ao ver 2 itens na ListBox2, ele, pelos PID's dos processos, visse qual usa mais memória, e definisse esse como "ProcID". Poderiam me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Editei. Tinha esquecido de colocar o "Form_Load" no code, daí não ia dar pra entender o código do timer...

Comment: Porque utiliza duas `ListBox`? Qual o objetivo do seu código?

Comment: Na primeira, serão adicionados todos os processos sendo executados no momento. Na segunda, serão adicionados os PIDS desses processos. Depois utilizando FOR, ele muda o selectedindex da listbox1, a qual contém todos os processos, e verifica se o item selecionado corresponde à variável "actualProcess", se corresponder, ele irá definir o selectedindex da listbox2 para o mesmo selectedindex da listbox1, e então, teremos o pid do processo. E então o pid do processo será adicionado à listbox3. (Editei o código)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código pode ser largamente otimizado, isto se o que percebi está correto.

Reestruturei-o para o seguinte:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TopMost = True
    Focus()
    PreencheListBox()
    Proc.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PreencheListBox()
    ListBox1.DataSource = Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(Function(r) r.ProcessName).ToList()
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "Id"
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcessName"
End Sub

Private Sub Proc_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Proc.Tick
    PreencheOutraListBox("explorer")
End Sub

Private Sub PreencheOutraListBox(ByVal processName As String)
    Dim processesSource = CType(ListBox1.DataSource, List(Of Process))
    Dim processes = processesSource?.Where(Function(r) String.Compare(r.ProcessName, processName) = 0).ToList()

    If processes?.Count > 0 Then
        Dim process = processes.OrderByDescending(Function(r) r.WorkingSet64).FirstOrDefault()

        If Not process Is Nothing Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(process.Id)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

A propriedade `WorkingSet64` devolve a quantidade de memória alocada para determinado processo, então ordenei a lista por aí e apenas coloquei na nova `ListBox` esse PID.

De salientar que o nome do processo no `Timer` é apenas um exemplo (porque de X em X tempo vai resultar no mesmo).